# Vim intercepts ssh escape

Tags: ssh, vim, escape-characters

There is no issues to solve (that I know of). I am trying to better understand ssh.

On my system the ssh escape character is tilde (~). If I ssh somewhere I can use it as expected:

```
me@local$ ssh remote
me@remote$                # here I press tilde, control+z
[1]+  Stopped                 ssh remote
me@local$
```

All is well. However, if I run `vim` on the remote, suddenly vim sees the escape character. It seems like the escape character is no longer sent *to* `ssh` but instead *through* `ssh`, as if it was not an escape character.

```
me@local$ ssh remote
me@remote$ vim
# vim opens, here I press tilde, control+z
[1]+  Stopped                 vim
me@remote$
```

My question is, how is `vim` affecting the behavior of `ssh`'s escape character?

Comment: How does it work if you press the Return/Enter key before you press the tilde and Control+Z keys?

Comment: you can change the default with : `ssh -e 'anotherchar' ...` . the value "none" disables the special char and let them all pass through ssh

Comment: @SottoVoce if I do this, it does put ssh in the background. Why does Return/Enter change the behavior? And where is this documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments:

> How does it work if you press the Return/Enter key before you press the tilde and Control+Z keys? - Sotto Voce

> if I do this, it does put ssh in the background. Why does Return/Enter change the behavior? And where is this documented? - kill -9

Answering in reverse because the 2nd question has a more concise answer than the 1st:

#### Where is this (pressing Return before ~) documented?

The [ESCAPE CHARACTERS section of the Openssh man page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#ESCAPE_CHARACTERS) describes the command escape sequence to make the `ssh` client program take actions rather than forward keystrokes to the remote server.  The second paragraph has this sentence:

> The escape character must always follow a newline to be interpreted as special.

I wouldn't blame you if you find this to be a little vague and easy to overlook.  It used to be worse!  I first encountered the `~.` exit command in the 1990s with the SunOS 4.x `tip` command, whose [man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/tip/) said:

> A tilde (~) appearing as the first character of a line is an escape signal which directs tip to perform some special action.

This description left the reader to infer that, for the `~` key to be *the first character of a line*, the preceding keystroke would have to be Return/Enter.  Inference is not a good thing in documentation.  Most people missed the point, and were frustrated when `tip` seemed to ignore their `~.` (quit) commands.  The `ssh` man page has improved the description to be a little more explicit.

The reason these `~` escape sequences (which seem to date back to `rlogin` in 1981's 4.1BSD Unix) have the requirement to be preceded by Return/Enter is to prevent the appearance of `~.` (perhaps in a file upload to the remote server) from unintentionally disconnecting the session.

#### Why do my remote sessions running vim seem to need the extra Return keypress?

*(my paraphrase of your question)*

I can't tell you precisely why your remote session invoking `vim` needs an "extra" Return keypress compared to running some other command.  But I can offer a couple of educated guesses:

- When you've run `vim` on the remote server and pressed Return, you've typed some other keystrokes before you typed `~Ctrl-Z`.  Perhaps you pressed the arrow or the `h`, `j`, `k`, `l` cursor movement keys.  Or `Ctrl-L` to refresh the display.
- If you haven't pressed any keys between invoking `vim` and typing `~Ctrl-Z`, then perhaps the `vim` program is sending a character sequence to your terminal program asking for status and your terminal program is sending back characters as the answer.  This kind of query and answer are typically not displayed by terminal programs.  The answer sequence comes from your terminal program just like your keystrokes, and your ssh client sees other characters preceded the `~` instead of Return.

The second guess is less likely than the first, but I have encountered it on some occasions.

#### Ultimately...

The most reliable way to send an escape sequence/command to your ssh client program is to think of the escape character as actually being two characters: Return followed by tilde.  For most commands, this makes the sequence three keystrokes instead of two.

Comment: I can confirm that between typing `vim` and trying the escape sequence, I did not type any other characters (even "command" ones like `j` or `k`). I can't confirm Your second educated guess, but it seems to fit all the criteria.